# he hecho una base de datos anidada con mongodb, pero no me agrega los datos del subdocumento

Tags: mongodb

estes es mi modelo, quiero llenar el array menu con informacion enviada desde un formulario
nombrecate es una categoria de carta de restaurant, y menu son los diferentes menu que puede tener una carta.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const cartaschema = new Schema({
    nombrecate : {type: String, required: true },
       menu:[{ `introducir el código aquí`
    nombremenu :{type:String, required:true, } , `introducir el código aquí`
    descripcion : {type:String, required:true, } , 
    precio:{type:Number, required:true, } ,  
    precioenvio: {type:Number, required:true, } ,
    date :{type:Date, required:true, } ,
   
    }]

 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('carta', cartaschema)
```

pero a la hora de guardar los datos no me los guarda guarda, pero si me aparece un array vacio

aqui esta la ruta ,modelo es el nombre del modelo de la base de datos.

```
router.post('/home/menu-enviado',async (req,res)=>{
  // const {nombrecate,nombremenu,descripcion,precio,precioenvio}= req.body//recibe el name='' de  cada propiedad
  const body= req.body;
  
  const{nombrecate} =req.body;
  
  const newcarta = new modelo({nombrecate})
  console.log(newcarta._id)
  console.log(req.body.nombremenu)
  await newcarta.save();
  
 
   
    modelo.updateOne({'_id': newcarta._id}, {
      
      $push:{
        'menu':{
          nombremenu: req.body.nombremenu,
          descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
          precio: req.body.precio,
          precioenvio: req.body.precioenvio
        }
      }
    }
    );
    
    res.redirect('/carta');
   
     

});
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `modelo`? Dónde lo defines? Si modelo es el objeto creado a partir del esquema de carta, mejor llamarle `cartaModel` o algo relacionado con la carta. Porqué haces un `save` primero y luego un `update`? Si estás creando un documento de `carta` entonces o haces el `save` considerando todos los datos (así no tienes que actualizar) o simplemente usa `insertOne`.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios detalles de implementación. Vamos a ver como los solucionamos uno por uno.

**PRIMERO**

El modelo de datos debe tener un nombre coherente con la entidad que representan. Por ello, mi sugenrencia es que uses un nombre que represente realmente dicha entidad.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const MenuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombremenu: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    descripcion: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    precio: {
        type: Number,
        required:true
    },  
    precioenvio: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    } ,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
}, { _id: false });  // con _id: false, evito crear un campo _id en el subdocumento

const CartaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombrecate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    menu: {
        type: [ MenuSchema ]
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Carta', CartaSchema)
```

Como puedes observar he separado la definición de Schema del Menú fuera de la Carta, de esta forma es mucho más sencillo mantener el código. Al hacerlo así, debo decidir si al crear o agregar un objeto al Array de `menu`, se crearé un valor de `_id` o no. En este caso he dicho que no, pasando como opción a la creación del Schema el valor `{ _id: false }`. Para más información puedes leer la [documentación sobre tipo Schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schemas)

Otra cosa que he hecho es usar *PascalCase* (o *UpperCamelCase*) para nombrar tanto mis esquemas como mi modelo de datos.

**SEGUNDO**

Para crear una nueva carta tienes varias opciones, pero voy a resaltar el problema que tienes y cómo solucionarlo, para luego escribir una alternativa a tu código que sea más legible.

En tu caso, el problema es que estás llamando al método [`updateOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.updateOne()) de forma incorrecta. En realidad está incompleta la llamada.

El método `updateOne` puede recibir una función `callback` (en versiones de Mongoose 6.x o anteriores) o puede ser usada con `await` o con `then`.

Tu no has hecho nada de ello:

```js
//...
modelo.updateOne({'_id': newcarta._id}, {
    $push:{
        'menu': {
            nombremenu: req.body.nombremenu,
            descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
            precio: req.body.precio,
            precioenvio: req.body.precioenvio
        }
    }
});
// ...
```

Entonces lo que está pasando es que estás creando un [Objeto Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html) que por sí solo no actualiza la base de datos a menos que pases la función `callback` o hagas uso de `await` y llames a `exec()`, o uses `then()`.

**Usando una función `callback`**

Si usas Mongoose 6.11.5 o anterior, la forma de hacer la llamada será:

```js
//...
modelo.updateOne({'_id': newcarta._id}, {
    $push:{
        'menu': {
            nombremenu: req.body.nombremenu,
            descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
            precio: req.body.precio,
            precioenvio: req.body.precioenvio
        }
    }
}, (error, carta) => {
    // se ha ejecutado la actualización
    if(error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.redirect('/error');
    }
    console.log(carta);
    return res.redirect('/carta');
});
//...
```

Como se observa, la lógica de `res.redirect` se ejecuta dentro de la función `callback` que he pasado como último argumento a `updateOne`.

**Usando `then`**

Debes tomar en cuenta que aunque podemos usar `await` y `then` sobre un Objeto Query, [éste no es una Promesa](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises)

Una forma de usar `then` en tu código actual sería:

```js
//...
modelo.updateOne({'_id': newcarta._id}, {
    $push:{
        'menu': {
            nombremenu: req.body.nombremenu,
            descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
            precio: req.body.precio,
            precioenvio: req.body.precioenvio
        }
    }
}).then((carta) => {
    // se ha ejecutado la actualización
    console.log(carta);
    return res.redirect('/carta');}
);
// ...
```

Puedes ver que he encadenado `then` a mi llamada a `updateOne` y es dentro de la función que recibe `then` en donde voy a implementar la lógica para `res.redirect`.

**Usando `await`**

Podemos usar `await` delante de la llamada a `updateOne` de esta forma no necesitamos usar una función `callback` ni usar `then`. Pero si realmente queremos que `updateOne` devuelva una Promesa que pueda resolver o rechazar, debemos convertir el Objeto Query en una Promesa usando el método `exec()` encadenado a la llamada a `updateOne`, por ejemplo:

```js
//...
await modelo.updateOne({'_id': newcarta._id}, {
    $push:{
        'menu': {
            nombremenu: req.body.nombremenu,
            descripcion: req.body.descripcion,
            precio: req.body.precio,
            precioenvio: req.body.precioenvio
        }
    }
}).exec();  // <= ejecuta la actualización y devuelve una Promesa
// ...
```

**Mejora**

La siguiente es una mejora al código que muestras en tu pregunta, relacionado con la forma de crear un nuevo Menú en una Carta.

Supongamos que escribimos un nuevo menú y lo enviamos al Servidor para ser almacenado en la colección de Cartas. Tienes 2 posibles escenarios:

1. La carta no existe (y por supuesto el menú tampoco)
2. La carta existe, pero el menú no.

Ante esta incertidumbre, mi solución es usar el método [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) pero usando la opción [`upsert`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#upsert) establecida a `true`, que significa: *si el documento existe, lo actualizo, si no existe, lo creo.*

Mi código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
router.post('/home/menu-enviado', async (req, res) => {
    const { body } = req;
    if(!body) {
        return res.redirect('/error');
    }
    const { nombrecate } = body;
    if(!nombrecate) {
        return res.redirect('/error');
    }
    const newMenu = {
        nombremenu: body.nombremenu,
        descripcion: body.descripcion,
        precio: body.precio,
        precioenvio: body.precioenvio
    }
    const update = {
        $push: {
            menu: newMenu
        },
        $setOnInsert: {
            menu: [ newMenu ]
        }
    }
    try {
        const carta = await CartaModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            { nombrecate: nombrecate },
            update,
            { upsert: true, new: true }
        ).exec();
    
        console.log(carta);  
        return res.redirect('/carta');
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
        return res.redirect('/error');
    }
});
```

Ahora el código se ve un poco más limpio, además, al estar trabajando con Promesas, estoy usando un bloque `try ... catch` para poder manejar el caso en que la Promesa sea rechazada.

También te podrás dar cuenta que el objeto llamado `update` dispone de 2 propiedades: [`$push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) y [`$setOnInsert`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/). Esto es porque estoy usando la opción `upsert` establecida a `true`. Por lo tanto, si el documento de Carta no existe, no habrá ningún Array de menú al que hacerle `$push`, por ello uso:

```
$setOnInsert: {
    menu: [ newMenu ]
}
```

haciendo que al insertar una nueva carta, el valor del campo `menu` sea un Array cuyo único elemento es el nuevo menú creado a partir de la solicitud.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y aclare tus dudas.

Comment: mauricio muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder de esa manera tan detallada, aprendi mucho con tu ayuda..Bendiciones.